# Qt error: QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record when trying to retrive a stat from a table (QComboBox)

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qt5, qsqlquery

this is the code I'm using to get the GoalsFor stat from [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLb6H.png) after the user chooses a team from a ComboBox [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dV8P3.png) using this code:

```
 void MainWindow::on_hometeam_currentIndexChanged(const QString &hometeam)
{
  QString hteam(hometeam);

  QSqlQuery q("SELECT GoalsForH FROM teams WHERE TEAM=hteam");
  q.exec();
  int fieldNo = q.record().indexOf("hometeam");
  q.next();

  qDebug() << q.value(fieldNo).toInt();

}
```

But this is what the debugger always shows whenever I choose a team:

```
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
0
```

I tried everything I came across on the net and it seems like I'm doing exactly what other users or even the documentation say yet to no avail, any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: What's the return value from `q.exec()` and `q.next()`? Try `if (!q.exec()) qDebug() << q.lastError();`

Comment: @chrisMM thanks for the reply, it still shows QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
0

Comment: Okay, but what is the result of `exec` and `next`?

Comment: @ChrisMM I added a else qDebug()<<well executed; to your bit of code and it gives me the "well executed" message but it still gives the no valid record

Comment: And the result of q.next? As a quick look, your SQL is not actually valid. You're missing string markers in the where clause.

Comment: @ChrisMM Ah but the one for next gives a QSqlError("", "", "") before no valid record

Comment: `hteam` in your SQL isn't valid. I'm surprised `exec` works. It shouldn't.

Comment: Yo mean [well he're what happens](https://imgur.com/a/bh21mAO) what changes would you recommend ?

Comment: Basically, that is telling you that nothing is returned from the query. See my answer and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the SQL itself; since `hteam` isn't actually defined in SQL. I would instead recommend using the `prepare` function, which can also deal with filtering strings to prevent SQL injections. Something like the below should give you the result you are looking for.

```
void MainWindow::on_hometeam_currentIndexChanged(const QString &hometeam)
{
  QString hteam(hometeam);

  QSqlQuery q;
  q.prepare("SELECT GoalsForH FROM teams WHERE TEAM=:hteam");
  q.bindValue(":hteam", hteam);
  if ( !q.exec() ) {
    qDebug() << q.lastError();
  } else {
    int fieldNo = q.record().indexOf("GoalsForH");
    while ( q.next() ) {
      qDebug() << q.value(fieldNo).toInt();
    }
  }
}
```

You were also grabbing `indexOf("hometeam")`, which isn't actually returned by the query. This then returns `-1` which wouldn't be valid. Change this to `"GoalsForH"` to get the proper column index.

Comment: nah still same error lol thank you so much for your time and effort though I really appreciate it

Comment: Are you passing in a team that exists?

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` clause entirely. Also, try printing out `q.lastQuery()` and `q.boundValues()`

Comment: it gives me 21 `QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
0` s which is weird because I only have 20 teams on the table

Comment: @truxter, can you clarify... You are still getting the same error with the code I gave? That shouldn't be possible, since nothing should be printed if there's no results

Comment: [here's what happens](https://imgur.com/a/3bI55Zd) it basically gives the same error but 21 times, and again I', extremely grateful for your efforts and help

Comment: Oh, haha. I finally see the problem. Please see my updated answer.